# Library errors when running python script on Amazon Linux instance

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pygsheets

I am trying to get a script up and running on AWS Lambda and I have had some issues running the script.

To go through each of my problems. I first prepared the script using virtualenv and uploaded it. When I tried to invoke the script, I received the following error.

```
Payload:
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'pygsheets'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}
```

After doing that, I found someone who [mentioned](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13465) that they had trouble if they tried to prepare libraries on their system but were able to successfully create the script on an EC2 instance.

After trying that, I was still unsuccessful. As a precautionary measure, I attempted to run the script on the EC2 instance. After adding the location of the library folder, I was able to progress a little farther.

Now I am seemingly caught in an library error loop with the following two errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "handler.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pygsheets as py
  File "/home/ec2-user/package/pygsheets/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pygsheets.authorization import authorize
  File "/home/ec2-user/package/pygsheets/authorization.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pygsheets.client import Client
  File "/home/ec2-user/package/pygsheets/client.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pygsheets.drive import DriveAPIWrapper
  File "/home/ec2-user/package/pygsheets/drive.py", line 6, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import discovery
  File "/home/ec2-user/package/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 50, in <module>
    import google.api_core.client_options
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.api_core'
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "handler.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pygsheets as py
  File "/home/ec2-user/package/pygsheets/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pygsheets.authorization import authorize
  File "/home/ec2-user/package/pygsheets/authorization.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.oauth2'
```

If I run `python3 -m pip install --target /home/ec2-user/package --upgrade google-auth` I get the first error when I run the script.
If I then run `python3 -m pip install --target ./package --upgrade google-api_core` I'll get the second error when I run the script.
If I then try to fix the second error I'll just get caught with the first error again.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can proceed?

Some possibly useful information
When I made the virtualenv I did not have any trouble running the script. I only had trouble after uploading to AWS.

To summarize

- Tried using virtualenv to prepare libraries.
- No issues when running script in virtualenv locally, but `No module named 'pygsheets'` error
  after uploading the files to AWS Lambda.
- Tried using EC2 instance to prepare. Got `No module named 'google.oauth2'` error.
- When trying to troubleshoot on EC2 instance, got a `No module` loop

Comment: Have you added your libraries in lambda layers?

Comment: No, I like I mentioned, I used virtualenv to prepare the libraries. I then uploaded everything. I tried uploading just with a zip and also with Serverless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue. It seems like there was a problem with my Docker. I no longer had any library problems after I reinstalled that software.